# XNA C# getting 12 triangle faces of a cube, given (MIN,MAX) of BoundingBox

Tags: c#, xna, cube

Is there a easy way or c# class to get 12 triangles of a cube 
where, only (MIN,MAX) coordinates are known for the BoundingBox cube 
I want to use  PrimitiveType.TriangleList  for rendering face of cube but don't know how to get
static indices array of 12 triangles which can be defined by , MIN ,MAX vertices of the cube.

I am using C# with XNA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out .... This is working for me ..not sure if it is geralized way to do it

```
static float a , b , h ;

        static Vector3 MinV = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        static Vector3 MaxV = new Vector3(a, b, h);

        Vector3 topLeftBack = new Vector3(MinV.X, MaxV.Y, MinV.Z);
        Vector3 topRightBack = new Vector3(MaxV.X, MaxV.Y, MinV.Z);
        Vector3 bottomLeftBack = new Vector3(MinV.X, MinV.Y, MinV.Z); //min
        Vector3 bottomRightBack = new Vector3(MaxV.X, MinV.Y, MinV.Z);

        Vector3 topLeftFront = new Vector3(MinV.X, MaxV.Y, MaxV.Z);
        Vector3 topRightFront = new Vector3(MaxV.X, MaxV.Y, MaxV.Z);  //max  
        Vector3 bottomLeftFront = new Vector3(MinV.X, MinV.Y, MaxV.Z);
        Vector3 bottomRightFront = new Vector3(MaxV.X, MinV.Y, MaxV.Z);
```